# Can't add foreign key constraint, the foreign key referred to is not null and has the same type

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

Here is a small part of my SQL query, the foreign key that I'm referring to is not null and has the same type where did I go wrong?

```
Create table `Time` (
`Year` year not null,
`Semester` char(2) not null,
primary key (`Year`, `Semester`)
);

Create table `Allocation` (
`Student_ID` int unsigned not null,
`Time_Year` year not null,
`Time_Semester` char(2) not null,
primary key (`Timeslot_Year`, `Timeslot_Semester`, `Student_ID`),
constraint fk_year_allocation foreign key (`Time_Year`) references `Time`(`Year`),
constraint fk_semester_allocation foreign key (`Time_Semester`) references `Time`(`Semester`),
);
```

Comment: You have some other issues in your statements. Please share an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from fixing the typos such as the ending comma in the second table and the

```
primary key (`Timeslot_Year`, `Timeslot_Semester`),
```

should be

```
primary key (`Time_Year`, `Time_Semester`),
```

You need to add an index on the  `Semester` column .

> Why `constraint fk_year_allocation foreign key (Time_Year) references Time(Year)` is working ?

From `primary key (Year, Semester)` only the left one is used.

See [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TZxmef8C)

See [Conditions and Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#:%7E:text=Creating%20a%20foreign%20key%20constraint,need%20not%20be%20the%20same.) when dealing with foreign keys.